# The following text is inheriting the font-size of p, even though p is not an ancestor

Tags: css

In the example below collected from:

http://6.470.scripts.mit.edu/css_exercises/exercise5.html

```
.wrapper1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.wrapper2 {
  clear: left;
}
.p1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}
.p2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="wrapper2">
  <p class="p1">MIT 6.470</p>
  <p class="p2">Learn Web Programming this IAP</p2>
  <a href="">Comprehensive Curriculum</a>
  <a href="">Insightful Guest Lectures</a>
  <a href="">Interaction with Sponsors</a>
  <a href="">$30,000+ in Total Prizes</a>
</div>
Copyright © 2012 MIT 6.470
</div>
```

With this style what happens is that the links after `p.p2` is placed adjacent to the `p.p2` but my understanding is that `p` is block element so it should not allow any other element adjacent to it. Secondly, The size of the links is the same as that of `p.p2`, even though `p.p2` is not an ancestor for the links. How can this be possible?

Comment: Because of the typo `</p2>`, the paragraph tag was never closed. As a result, the anchor tags were actually nested inside the paragraph tag, which is why they were inheriting styles from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

```
 <p class="p2">Learn Web Programming this IAP</p2>
```

you need to change `</p2>` to `</p>`